# Finding value with most common condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I am having a lot of trouble with PostgreSQL trying to figure out how to find the most common value that fits a specific criteria. The `ID` is the ID number of the book, meaning repeating numbers means there are multiple copies of the book.

I have 2 tables here:

```
Table A:
=====+===================
ID   |   Condition
-------------------------
1    |   Taken
1    |   
1    |   Taken
1    |   
2    |   Taken
3    |   Taken
3    |   
3    |   Taken
3    |   Taken
4    |   
4    |   Taken  
etc.

Table B:
=====+===================
ID   |    Name
-------------------------
1    |    BookA
2    |    BookB
3    |    BookC
4    |    BookD
etc.
```

What I need is to simply find which book has the most copies taken and simply print out the name of the book. In this case all I need is:

```
BookC
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how to find how much each individual ID has books taken. I tried using a temp table something like so:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE MostCommon AS
    (SELECT ID
     FROM TableA
     WHERE SUM(CASE WHEN Condition>0 then 1 else 0 END)
    )
    SELECT NAME FROM TableB, MostCommon WHERE
    MostCommon.ID = TableB.ID;
```

But it either throws an error or simply doesn't give me what I need. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The data make no sense; what does it mean that there are multiple records that are completely identical? Please post a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of SQL code we can run to get the same schema and data as you.

Comment: @bignose The "ID" number is the ID of the book. There are multiple copies of each, which is why the ID number repeats multiple times in the first table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so firstly I assumed that your columns and tables names are case sensitive which means you must use duble quote marks. To print most "taken" book name with number of "taken" copies, you can use simple aggragete `count()`, then order the output descending and at the end limit the output to 1 row, like:

```
SELECT
    b."ID",
    b."Name",
    count(*) as takenCount
FROM "TableA" a
    JOIN "TableB" b ON a."ID" = b."ID"
WHERE a."Condition" = 'Taken'
GROUP BY b."ID", b."Name"
ORDER BY 3 DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thank you. This was the clearest and most understandable answer. And it does indeed work.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE MostCommon AS
(SELECT id, (sum(ID)/id) book_taken FROM tableA  where condition = 'Taken' group by id);


select name from tableB t2 join MostCommon mc on mc.id = t2.id where mc.id in (select max(book_taken) from MostCommon)
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the data sensible (i.e. no duplicate records), I have to change the schema a little.

```sql
CREATE TABLE book_condition (
    created TIMESTAMP,
    book_id INTEGER,
    condition VARCHAR,
    PRIMARY KEY (created, book_id));

INSERT INTO book_condition (created, book_id, condition)
VALUES
    ('2016-01-01 08:30', 1, 'Taken'),
    ('2016-01-01 08:35', 1, ''),
    ('2016-01-01 08:40', 1, 'Taken'),
    ('2016-01-01 08:45', 1, ''),
    ('2016-01-01 08:50', 2, 'Taken'),
    ('2016-01-01 08:55', 3, 'Taken'),
    ('2016-01-01 09:00', 3, ''),
    ('2016-01-01 09:05', 3, 'Taken'),
    ('2016-01-01 09:10', 3, 'Taken'),
    ('2016-01-01 09:15', 4, ''),
    ('2016-01-01 09:20', 4, 'Taken');

CREATE TABLE book (
    book_id INTEGER,
    name VARCHAR,
    PRIMARY KEY (book_id));

INSERT INTO book (book_id, name)
VALUES
    (1, 'BookA'),
    (2, 'BookB'),
    (3, 'BookC'),
    (4, 'BookD');
```

Then, the question breaks down into:

- How many copies of each book were ever taken?

```sql
SELECT
    book_id,
    COUNT(book_id) AS total_taken
FROM book_condition
WHERE
    condition = 'Taken'
GROUP BY book_id
;
```

```
 book_id | total_taken 
---------+-------------
       1 |           2
       2 |           1
       3 |           3
       4 |           1
(4 rows)
```

- How to rank records by `total_taken` value?

```sql
SELECT
    book_id,
    total_taken,
    RANK() OVER (
        ORDER BY total_taken DESC
        ) AS total_taken_rank
FROM (
    SELECT
        book_id,
        COUNT(book_id) AS total_taken
    FROM book_condition
    WHERE
        condition = 'Taken'
    GROUP BY book_id
    ) AS bt
ORDER BY total_taken_rank ASC
;
```

```
 book_id | total_taken | total_taken_rank 
---------+-------------+------------------
       3 |           3 |                1
       1 |           2 |                2
       2 |           1 |                3
       4 |           1 |                3
(4 rows)
```

- How to get the name of the book in a query result containing its key (`id`) value?

```sql
SELECT
    b.book_id,
    b.name,
    bt.total_taken,
    RANK() OVER (
        ORDER BY bt.total_taken DESC
        ) AS total_taken_rank
FROM
    book AS b
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            book_id,
            COUNT(book_id) AS total_taken
        FROM book_condition
        WHERE
            condition = 'Taken'
        GROUP BY book_id
        ) AS bt
        USING (book_id)
ORDER BY
    total_taken_rank ASC,
    book_id ASC
;
```

```
 book_id | name  | total_taken | total_taken_rank 
---------+-------+-------------+------------------
       3 | BookC |           3 |                1
       1 | BookA |           2 |                2
       2 | BookB |           1 |                3
       4 | BookD |           1 |                3
(4 rows)
```

- How to get only the highest-ranking records in the result?

```sql
SELECT
    br.book_id,
    br.name,
    br.total_taken
FROM (
    SELECT
        b.book_id,
        b.name,
        bt.total_taken,
        RANK() OVER (
            ORDER BY bt.total_taken DESC
            ) AS total_taken_rank
    FROM
        book AS b
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT
                book_id,
                COUNT(book_id) AS total_taken
            FROM book_condition
            WHERE
                condition = 'Taken'
            GROUP BY book_id
            ) AS bt
            USING (book_id)
    ) AS br
WHERE
    total_taken_rank = 1
;
```

```
 book_id | name  | total_taken 
---------+-------+-------------
       3 | BookC |           3
(1 row)
```